# Cover $2n$ points on the plane with $n$ non-overlapping circles, each containing exactly two points.

Tags: contest-math, plane-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

I have found this tough combinatorial geometry question in some Soviet math competition circa $1972$. It looks very simple (and rather natural), yet I cannot find the proof for quite some time now.

*$2n$ points are given on the plane. Prove that there exist $n$ non-overlapping circles, each containing exactly two given points.*

**Note**: Circle here means a **filled circle**, not a circumference.

There is a version of this problem which is, probably, easier... yet not so easy that I can figure the solution right away.

*Given an arbitrary subset of the plane consisting of $2n$ points, is it true that there always exist $n$ non-overlapping squares, each containing exactly two points from the subset?*

In both versions the covering shapes (circles or squares) are allowed to touch each other but they cannot have common interior points.

---

It turns out that the first statement is simply false. As a counterexample, consider a very large natural number $n$ and then the set of $2n$ points, consisting of $2n-1$ vertices of a regular polygon with $2n-1$ sides plus its center. Proving that this set is, indeed, a counterexample to the first statement, is not trivial. The proof is technically tough (despite being rather straightforward), since it requires wading through quite a few boring geometric and trigonometric inequalities.

However, we can discard the requirement that the circles do not overlap, replacing it with the requirement that their intersections do not contain any points from the given set. Thus, the seemingly more reasonable variant of the original problem looks like this:

*$2n$ points are given on the plane. Prove that they can be covered by $n$ disks, each of them containing exactly two of the points.*

The resulting problem is still not at all trivial. I guess that the proof can be attempted using Delaunay triangulation... remember, however, that the given set does not have to consist of points in general position.

Comment: There is a similar problem: group the $2n$ points in groups of $2$ so that the segments determined do not intersect. Clearly this is a stronger demand. Very nice!

Comment: Your counter-example, does not seem obvious to me. For example, if you give me the vertices of a 99-sided regular polygon and the center point, it seems rather clear there exist 50 non-intersecting circles that go through 2 points each. 1 large circle goes through the top, center, and 3/4 of the way along the bottom line segment. You then have an even number of tiny circles running along both halves.

Comment: @Bobby Ocean . No, it's not obvious. But if $n$ is large enough - say, $n > 1000$ - then the following can be argued. First of all, we can assume (by shrinking the circles where necessary) that all circles are such that their circumferences pass through the corresponding pairs of points. Second, let the vertices of the polygon lie on the unit circle centered at zero. Let one circle cover the center and the top; denote $\alpha = 2\pi/(2n-1)$.

Comment: Then it is pretty obvious that its radius must lie between $1/2$ and $1/2 + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \approx \sin \alpha/2$. The next step is to prove that the vertices next to the top one (on the left and on the right) must be paired up with their neighbors. Yet another step is to prove that the radius of the circle covering them cannot be too small (e.g., it must be at least $1/10$). Finally, two such circles must intersect.

Comment: I must not have been clear in my last comment. Say the regular polygon has 99,999 sides. Draw the straight vertical line from the top point, through the center, down through the half way point of the bottom two vertices. It is clear there is now vertices running along the left and right that can be paired consecutively. It is clear that neither the line nor the circles intersect. Now deviate the line by $\epsilon$ so that it is a very giant circle. Is this not a solution to any odd sided polygon with center?

Comment: @BobbyOcean: I think your solution only works when the number of sides is 1 mod 4 (otherwise the two halves won't both have an even number of points), but I think it's possible to send the large circle through the next midpoint over and still avoid any problems in the 3 mod 4 case.

Comment: Yes agreed. The point is that one very very large circle and a bunch on sequential small circles seems to work fine.

Comment: @BobbyOcean: I am not sure I understand your example. Won't the huge circle cover almost half of our $2n$ points (instead of just two) and also intersect quite a bunch of small circles (literally containing them)? I guess I should have emphasized that we are talking about circles, not circumferences.

Comment: Well, my comment/example doesn't make sense anymore since you changed the definition of circle in your edit. lol. A circle normally always mean the set of points equi-distance to a center.

Comment: @JimT For future reference, a fairly typical convention in mathematics is to use the term *disk* to refer to a circular region's interior, and circle only to the 1D border thereof. (People do sometimes use the word "circle" to mean the former thing, but it tends to be in places where this is clear from context.)

Comment: Sorry, my math education hails back to 1970-80s, and I suspect that the terminology back then was mainly British. So we used words "circle" and "circumference" to mean what we now apparently call "disk" and "circle".

Answer (score 0):

An attempt: pair the points such that the sum of pairwise distances is minimal.  This give a solution to an older problem. It may solve this one too.

( that was a useful try, that in fact directed us to the solution, see below).

---

$\bf{Added:}$ In fact one should choose a pairing $A_i B_i$ such that the sum
$$\sum |A_i B_i|^2$$
is minimal. Then the circles with diameter $A_i B_i$ do not intersect.

For a convex quadrilateral, two circles with diamaters opposite edges intersect, while the other do not, and this depends on the angle of diagonals, and also, on which pair has sum of squares smaller.

For such a pairing, the segments $A_i B_i$ and $A_j B_j$ do not intersect, simple to see (assume the contrary, consider them diagonals, and choose instead the pair opposite acute angle).

Note that is also solves the older problem where the segments should not intersect. Now sometime the sum of squares minimum is also sum minimum, but it's not clear how that differs, and whether sum minimum does solve this problem at hand.

---

Here is a picture: in a convex quadrilateral, build circles with diameters the sides. Then those opposite circles intersect for which the corresponding diagonal angle is obtuse.

[image]

$\bf{Added:}$ Here is an example of a configuration of $4$ points giving some counterexamples. Consider an isosceles trapezoid with orthogonal diagonals, whose intersection cuts them into segments $a<b$. Now we have $\sqrt{2}(a+b) < 2 \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, so the sum of bases is $<$ sum of sides. Now modify a bit the angle of diagonal to make the bases oppose an obtuse angle. Now we get the example where the sum of sides is smallest, but the sum of squares is not.

$\bf{Added:}$ @Calvin Lin: was kind to point out that the proof does not work if $4$ of the points form a concave quadrilateral. Therefore, as it stands, the proof *only  works* for points that are vertices of a convex polygon, a restrictive condition.  I'll see what can be said about the general case.

Comment: Alas, no. This approach does not work. However, perhaps, we could try minimizing the sum of the values of some more complicated function of a pair of planar points.

Comment: @JimT: How about sum of squares of distances?  $L_2$ methods work in many cases. I am away from the desk at the moment

Comment: Is it clear that iteratively picking two point that are closest, and pairing them up, doesn't work?

Comment: Pairing the closest two points doesn't work. As a counterexample consider a convex quadrilateral where one of the diagonals is very short, intersecting the other one at its midpoint or close to it.

As for the sum of the squares, it's worth looking into it. The problem is though that we have to provide not only the matching (pairing the points up) but the corresponding encompassing circles themselves, making sure they do not overlap.

Comment: I don't see how this quadrilateral is a counterexample. Do you mean to consider discs instead of circles?

Comment: @Mathieu Rundström: it is quite possible that choosing closest unjoined pairs ( a greedy algorith) might not minimize sum of ( squared) distances.  I am still puzzled if there are configurations for which those with minimal sum ( but not sum of squares) still do not satisfy. Perhaps just look at a convex quadrilateral.. For your statement, perhaps again a quadrilateral with a tiny side but opposing an obtuse diagonal angle will do

Comment: FWIW The idea of "Circles with $A_iB_i$ as the diameter" will not work. For a counterexample, take the 4 points corresponding to the 3 vertices of an equilateral triangle and its center. Then, in any pairing, 2 of the vertices must be together. Their diameter-circle would then separate the center and the other vertex (eg by angle chasing), and hence intersects the other diameter-circle.  $\quad$ I did not read through your proof in detail to understand where it failed. You can apply it to this scenario and doublecheck. $\quad$ It's not clear to me why you got 2 upvotes either.

Comment: @Calvin Lin: that's a very good point!  I tell you where the proof does not work: if two segments do not form a convex quadrilateral, like in your example. Will see what can be done about it.Thanks!

Comment: The counterexample with the equilateral triangle and its center shows that this cannot be solved by finding some "minimizing" pairing of the points and then building the circles using the corresponding segments as diameters.  This is quite a non-trivial problem, and it does not yield to simple one-step solutions like that.

Comment: @JimT: Correct; added that in the answer. It does work in the particular case of the points forming a convex polygon.  I looked briefly at Voronyi and Delaunay cells, interesting in itself, no success so far.Worth considering particular cases.